# Execution of a script via jenkins returns error

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a script that runs ssh-add.

The script runs correctly with root user when executed via command line.

The script runs correctly with jenkins user when executed via command line.

The script does fail when executed via jenkins build.

The script:

```
PASS="MYPASS"
install -vm700 <(echo "echo $PASS") "$PWD/ps.sh"
[[ -z "$DISPLAY" ]] && export DISPLAY=:0
< ../ssh/pk SSH_ASKPASS="$PWD/ps.sh" ssh-add - && shred -n3 -uz  $PWD/ps.sh
```

The log when executed via command line:

```
[root@machine xxx-datalake-dataflow]# ./unlock_ssh.sh 
‘/dev/fd/63’ -> ‘/usr/src/user_dev/xxx-datalake-dataflow/ps.sh’
Identity added: (stdin) (email)
```

The log when executed via jenkins:

```
+ cd /usr/src/user_dev/xxx-datalake-dataflow
+ ./unlock_ssh.sh ****
./unlock_ssh.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./unlock_ssh.sh: line 2: `install -vm700 <(echo "echo $PASS") "$PWD/ps.sh"'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The jenkins build instructions:

```
cd /usr/src/user_dev/xxx-datalake-dataflow

./unlock_ssh.sh $ADDSP
```

**Why does it fail when ran via jenkins build and how to fix this ?**

Comment: If the bash has entered posix mode. This error occur if you start bash with --posix argument or variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set when bash execution start.

Comment: To add to the comment given by amitbhosale : The error also occurs if the script does not run under bash at all, but under sh or dash or ash. How did you ensure that bash is used, and is not run in Posix mode? After all, you tagged your question as _shell_, from which I take that you don't even intend bash or ksh or zsh. Despite of this, you are using bash-specific constructs in your code. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also please check your file's encoding to make sure it is suitable for the target linux environment. (for example if you developed script on MAC and running on linux)
strip carriage returns from the file, if they are present)
`cat unlock_ssh.sh | -d "\r" > new_unlock_ssh.sh` then rename the file to unlock_ssh.sh

Comment: @user1934428 That was the problem. Thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: @amitbhosale : Interesting idea, but AFIK, the times where CR is used on the Mac are over since MacOS 10.4 Tiger, when they switched to BSD.

Comment: @user1934428, Thanks for sharing the information